# What happens first, MovieClip.onLoad() or Event.ENTER_FRAME?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs4

I'm making a small game in Flash as a school project, and I was wondering what would trigger first when a movie clip is placed-- the onLoad function, or the ENTER_FRAME event.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I removed onLoad, because it isn't actually called when the object is put on the stage.

```
var loaded:Boolean = false;
var angle:Number = 0; //in radians
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
function init():void {
    //get projectile position based on relation to mouse and spawning point.
    trace("init");
    loaded = true;
    this.angle = Math.atan2(mouseY - this.y, mouseX - this.x);
}
function update(e:Event):void {
    /* TRIG TIME! Move the object a certain amount
     * of pixels-- based on the delta, in the specified angle.
     */
    if (!loaded) {
        init();
    }
    trace("update");
    var slope:Number = Math.tan(angle);
}
```

This method still probably doesn't work, though...

Comment: Maybe you could use those two and add a trace() function to each one of them, like trace("OnLoad here") & trace("Enter frame") and just see what displayed on the output first, it's just a guess

Comment: I'd love to know the result :)

Comment: Well, I added the trace functions, but they're not showing up in the output window, so I don't think I'm looking at the right place, or the functions aren't getting called. Do you know where I'm supposed to find the trace's output? :I

Comment: Actually I managed to get update to work, but init isn't working.

Comment: Can you post some code so I can see how you tried to set it up?

Comment: Well, I ended up doing something different-- lemme add it to the question.

Comment: Actually, it's my bad. Actionscript 3 doesn't include the onLoad as Actionscript 2 did, I believe you can use Event.ADDED or Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE. I'll check it for you now and tell you what's loading first

Comment: I tried Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, and nothing happened, so I decided to call init() through the update function-- I feel like that's going to turn up errors, though. I'l try Event.ADDED.

Comment: Well, I moved the class to its own ActionScript file, gave it a constructor, and now everything is working like a charm!

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it too~ sorry it took me long, was busy doing other things hehe, but yeah firstly init() doesn't work on a timeline code (Which is why putting it in an AS file fixed it), ADDED worked great when I wrote it from the parent who's adding the movieclip, and if you wonder, ADDED works first, before ENTER_FRAME :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onLoad doesn't seem to work the way I expected it to in this case-- I solved this by changing the onLoad function to an ADDED_TO_STAGE event. I moved all of the actionscript code for the class out of the flash file, and into a separate actionscript file, and put the event listeners for `event.ENTER_FRAME` and `event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` events into the class' constructor, and the now entire class works like a charm.

```
public function Projectile() {
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    super();
}
```

The function init was called before the function update, and now I can continue with my work!

Special thanks to [Don](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548414/don) for helping me solve this dilemma

Answer (score 0):

In actionscript 3 you must add a listener, and not use onLoad,
So instead of MovieClip.onLoad() do:

```
MovieClip.addEventListener(Event.ADDED,mcLoaded);

function mcLoaded(e:Event):void {

trace("MovieClip added.");

}
```

As for the question asked, 
ADDED / ADDED_TO_STAGE run before ENTER_FRAME.

This solution is for timeline code (Not a separate .as file. OP has the solution for the other case.)